# Beginning C++: using if else, n--, number

Tags: c++, if-statement, sum

I am struggling to get this program to work. Could someone please look it over to see what is wrong? (The compiler says that sum_positive is not defined in this way.) Also, I have searched this problem and found an answer on here, but I did not see the problem that way and want to avoid plagiarism when I turn in my homework. Thank you!

9. Write a program that reads in ten whole numbers and that outputs the sum of all the numbers greater than zero, the sum of all the numbers less than zero (which will be a negative number or zero), and the sum of all the numbers, whether positive, negative, or zero. The user enters the ten numbers just once each and the user can enter them in any order. Your program should not ask the user to enter the positive numbers and the negative numbers separately.

Program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int number, n = 10, sum_positive = 0, sum_negative = 0, sum = 0;
    int count = 0, positive_count = 0, negative_count = 0;

    cout << "Please enter in 10 whole numbers, one at a time." << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter another number." << endl;
        cin >> number;
        n--;
    }
    while (n > 0);

    if (number >= 0)
    {
        sum_positive += number;
        //positive_count++; count++;
    }
    else
    {
        sum_negative += number;
        //negative_count++; count++;

    }


    sum = sum_positive + sum_negative;

    cout << sum_postive << endl;
    cout << sum_negative << endl;
    cout << sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because it's misspelled. Look closer.

Comment: SO is not somewhere you come to in order to avoid plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks I see it now.

Comment: But there is also the issue that the sum_positive = 10. How do I get it to add onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is a spelling mistake in your code of sum_positive in line (cout << sum_postive << endl;) - you have written sum_postive but you declared sum_positive.
2. you are running a loop and taking input in the same variable number, so it will overwrite all the inputs and will store only the last value in variable number which user entered. So your sum will always be equal to the last value user entered.

For this you need to use an array.
Example:

```
int number[10], n=10, sum_positive=0;
do{
    cout<<"e`enter code here`nter number:";
    cin>>number[n];
    n--;
}while(n>0);
```

now for sum also you need to use an loop.

If you do not know about an array, study about it how to use it.